# Mapping derived types using AutoMapper does not seem to work predictable

Tags: .net-core, automapper

We have setup a base class having multiple derived types

```
public class Base
{
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1 : Base { }

public class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public int Derived2Prop { get; set; }
}
```

We have also setup derived DTO models

```
public class BaseDto
{
    public int BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1Dto : BaseDto { }

public class Derived2Dto : Derived1Dto
{
    public int Derived2Prop { get; set; }
}
```

The AutoMapper configuration is mapped as follows

```
CreateMap<Base, BaseDto>()
    .Include<Derived1, Derived1Dto>()
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Derived1, Derived1Dto>()
    .Include<Derived2, Derived2Dto>()
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Derived2, Derived2Dto>()
    .ReverseMap();
```

I've written two unit tests, the first is working as expected, but the other unit test fails. To me this doesn't seem to be correct.

```
[Test]
public void MappingBaseDtoToDerived()
{
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddProfile(new BaseMapping());
    });
    var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

    var dto = new BaseDto { BaseProperty = 1234 };

    var model = new Derived2 { Derived2Prop = 5678 };

    var mapped = mapper.Map(dto, model);

    Assert.AreEqual(5678, model.Derived2Prop);
}

[Test]
public void MappingDerivedDtoToDerived()
{
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddProfile(new BaseMapping());
    });
    var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

    var dto = new Derived2Dto { BaseProperty = 1234 };

    var model = new Derived2 { Derived2Prop = 5678 };

    var mapped = mapper.Map(dto, model);

    Assert.AreEqual(5678, model.Derived2Prop);
}
```

Comment: Everything works as expected. Go through the docs and also check the tests in the repo. I'm not sure why you would expect the second test to pass.

Comment: To get the result you want, you only need one map, `CreateMap<BaseDto, Base>()`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for your response. I'm expecting the second test to pass, because the mapping for Derived2 and DerivedDto2 are configured to extend Base and BaseDto classes respectively. When mapping BaseDto -> Derived2 I see different behaviour than when mapping Derived2Dto -> Derived2.
Do you agree with me? If not, can you please elaborate on why you do expect this behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand any of that :) Again, go back to the documentation and the tests. Do you see how you just need a single map to make both tests pass?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu like you mentioned I only needed the one map: `CreateMap<BaseDto, Base>()`. Which is great! :D
In the docs is described how inheritance should be configured. In my mapping profile I tried to set this up, yet in my situation it was not necessary. Does this mean AutoMapper always tries to map derived types by default?

Comment: The map chosen depends on the runtime types of the source and destination objects. If there are multiple possibilities, `Include` helps, as the docs show. Here the base map seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map for the base types will be used when mapping derived types. There is no need for `Include` here. You just need `CreateMap<BaseDto, Base>()`.